# List of Lists based on field value in java

Tags: java

I recently attended an interview for BNP Paribas bank
I was asked this below collection based question.

There is a Employee class which contains reference to the Designation class

I was asked to write a helper class which takes List of Employees and returns the 
List of List of Employees grouped according to their Designation.

```
class Employee
{
    Designation designation;
    public Employee(Designation designation) {
        this.designation=designation;
    }
}

class Designation
{
    String des;
    public Designation(String des) {
        this.des=des;
    }

}

class Helper
{
    public static List<List<Employee>> groupList(List<Employee> empList)
    {
        List<List<Employee>> empGroupList=new ArrayList<List<Employee>>();

        for(Employee e:empList)
        {
            // more code goes here
        }

        return empGroupList;
    }

}
```

I answered the question assuming the Helper class has List of Designations but Interviewer said that Helper class is Generic and doesn't have a knowledge about designations.

Comment: OK, then where's your code attempt to generify your Helper class? If you don't have one, consider trying to make one on your own first as this is the best way to find out where your strengths and weakness WRT this concept are.

Comment: I couldn't able to come up with an answer and did some google with no luck. Thats why posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a `Map` internally, and then just convert its `values()` to a `List`:

```
public static List<List<Employee>> groupList(List<Employee> empList) {
    Map<String, List<Employee>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(Employee e : empList) {
        String designation = e.getDesignation();
        List<Employee> list = map.get(designation);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(designation, list);
        }
        list.add(e);
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
}
```